# Folder on my second hard drive lost and cant be find

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, hard-drive, windows-10

System: Ubuntu 22.04, Windows 10 (Dual boot)
Desktop environment: GNOME

My laptop has a dual-boot system with Linux 22.04 and Windows 10. Additionally, I have a built-in second hard drive that both systems can access. It contains only files (photos, Word docx, pdf, etc.). Yesterday, I moved this folder from the Linux system to this hard drive and edited a Word document within it. After that, I booted into Windows but couldn't find this folder there. Then, I booted into Linux and also couldn't find the folder there. I searched through the recycle bins of both systems and found nothing. I also used recovery programs on both systems (Testdisk for Ubuntu and Recovermyfile for Windows). However, there were no results regarding my missing files.

Comment: Did Windows restore the hibernation/fast startup and that made it just like it was before? Usually the Linux NTFS driver will not write into a hibernated NTFS drive.

Comment: I don't really know .